# Webcam automatically takes picture when the computer wakes up

Tags: windows-7, laptop, security, webcam

Is it possible to have the webcam take a picture if my computer is woken from sleep mode?

I have seen that there are some programs with motion detection, but I would prefer a method that takes a picture when the machine is clicked or key pressed.

Platform: [Windows 7 Ultimate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7_editions#Main_editions) 64-bit on an [Acer Aspire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acer_Aspire) 5755g.

Comment: Any possible answers to this would probably be platform-specific. I suggest you mention which platform you are interested in.

Comment: Good idea. I am using Windows 7 ultimate 64Bit on an Acer Aspire 5755g

Comment: WillNZ You should add that info to your question. I have edited your question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Windows OS, you can create a Task in Task Scheduler that when a user Un-Locked his account (Also when logged in) it capture the webcam.

**Required :**

A) a small command line Webcam Capture utility.

B) find out what is and how to work with Task Scheduler.

For required A) you can use this utility for taking picture : [Nirsoft WebCamImageSave](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/web_cam_image_capture.html)

For required B) You can search Google ! ([a bit Fun](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=How%20to%20Create%20task%20in%20Task%20Scheduler))

*1)* Open your Task Scheduler and create a task with trigger : `When Workstation Unlock`

*2)* in the Action tab make new action and select start program

*3)* you can browse that command line utility that you downloaded (nirsoft webcaminagesave for example.)

*4)* add these Parameters at the end of Nirsoft application path (With a SPACE between program path and parameters) :

> /capture /Filename "C:\CapturedImage.jpg"

the full path with parameters will be something like this:

> C:\MyFiles\WebCamImageSave.exe /capture /Filename
>   "C:\CapturedImage.jpg"

5) Just save it and restart your computer :)

if you do everything right, it will take pictures from your webcam anytime that anyone logged (and Locked) your account.

Comment: Thanks for this. What if I wanted to see who was touching the mouse or keyboard but not knowing the password to actually unlock the machine?

Comment: You can not do it easily! because windows blocks run the applications at Logon Screen for security reasons. But maybe there is some ways to do that. but i'm sorry because i can not say it for breaking security reasons. a tip: the easiest to do it is breaking Winlogon process. But it NOT RECOMMENDED

Comment: I have marked this as the answer as it seems the best solution for now.